# I am having difficulty reaching a web service. Any ideas what changes are needed on my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, asp-classic

I have struggled with this task for so long that I am hoping for a reprieve.

We have a web service called Validate on a separate server/domain.

Due to same domain restrictions, I came up with proxy server (code) to work around it.

The code below called Validate.asp, points to the webservice:

```
Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
http.Open "POST", "http://servername1/folder1/folder2/folder3/Validation/Validate", False
http.setRequestHeader "Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
http.Send Request.Form
Response.Write http.ResponseText
Response.End
%>
```

Then the code markup below invokes Validate.asp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form>
Enter name: <input id="user" /><br/>
Enter Pass: <input id="pass" /><br/>
<input type="button" value="Get web response via AJAX" onclick="ajaxViaProxy()" />
</form>
<hr/>
Ressponse: <div id="result"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxViaProxy( )
{
    var uname = document.getElementById("user").value;

    var upass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "Validate.asp", true );
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    http.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (http.readyState==4 && http.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
                "Response from web server was '" + http.responseText + "'";
        }
    }
    http.send("username=" + encodeURIComponent(uname)
         + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(upass));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If everything goes well, we should get response similar to this one below:

```
{"Value":{"TokenId":35,"LoginName":"validUser","Created":"2013-12-03T09:53:35","Expires":"2013-12-24T09:53:35","LastUsed":"2013-12-03T09:53:35"},"Status":0,"Message":null}
```

This is the exact response we get when I paste the code below into an address bar and hit the enter key:

```
http://servername/folder1/folder2/folder3/Validation/Validate?data={"User":"validUserName","Password":"validPassword"}
```

However, when I use the markup to invoke proxyValidate.asp, rather than get the response with token, I get the following:

```
{"Value":null,"Status":2,"Message":"Invalid username or password"}
```

Does anyone know what I need to change in the markup or in proxyValidate.asp so that when I run the code, I get a properly formatted URL string like this below?

```
http://servername/folder1/folder2/folder3/Validation/Validate?data={"User":"validUserName","Password":"validPassword"}
```

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: your final url suggests that the service expects a `data` parameter which contains a JSON string. you're doing just a plain form-based POT, passing in username/password fields+values, neither of which are a `data` parameter in json format.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks a lot for the prompt response.

Did you mean something like this to be put on proxyValidate.asp?

If yes, is it properly formatted?

`var data = '{"LoginName":"' + Request.Form["uname"] + '","Password":"'+Request.Form["upass"]+'"}';`

Comment: don't build json manually... consider a password that contains a `'` naturally. Boom. json syntax error. But yes, generally that's probably what's needed.

Comment: @MarcB< I don't know how to accomplish what you are suggesting.

Can I get some sample, please?

Thank you for your assistance.